# How to render the leaf component of tree component without re-render entire tree in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, tree, renderpartial

Imaging there is a JS object containing the definition of the tree. The definition of leaf looks like:

```
{title:'leaf A'}
```

The tree JS object looks like:

```
{{title:'leaf A', children:{title:'children of leaf A'}}}
```

The tree component is rendered and I would like to change the title of a leaf component when some event fired on leaf component. This can be done easily by hooking the event handler of tree component to leaf component and re-render tree component using setState(). However, as such change does not cause the structure change of the tree, tt would be better not to re-render the entire tree but re-render the leaf component instead. Is it possible to achieve this in reactjs? As the result, the title of leaf in the JS object used for tree rendering should be changed/replaced as well.

Comment: It seems that you don't understand how React works. It uses virtual DOM, so only parts that actually changed are re-rendered.

Comment: @hindmost i don't think it's smart to call out people when you yourself don't seem to understand what's going on. React components will re-render every time when their props / state change, whether you want it or not. Sometimes you don't want to re-render when a certain prop changes (a function that has new instance for example). Also i'd advise to stop using the term virtual DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shouldComponentUpdate method that accepts new props and new state and there you can decide if you want to re-render or not.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

  // Update this component ONLY when the prop someProp changes
  if (this.props.someProp !== nextProps.someProp) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

I recommend checking the high order component onlyUpdateForKeys from the recompose utility belt - https://github.com/acdlite/recompose

Comment: thanks a lot. looks like this is the only way which also mentioned in react docs. I finally decided that I would not optimise it because of 1. too early to optimise, so far looks OK as there is not much leafs on the tree. 2. the leaf is just the wrapper of another component in which the title gets changed, and that components in leafs will be different thus requires different logic of shouldComponentUpdate() method, moreover, the leafs gets re-render anyway and only the wrapped component will benefit from this optimisation.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer before there is a better one